# How to move files shared in OneDrive among drives

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I am using Microsoft Graph perform file operations on data in OneDrive. I have gained the access token with appropriate scopes and permissions (`Files.ReadWrite.All`).

A OneDrive user has shared a folder with me, which contains some files. Another user has given me rights to a the folder. I'm trying to move those files into my OneDrive but it doesn't allow me to do so. The client software is able to perform this operation (it might be doing it copy and then delete operation).

However I can copy those shared files into my account, and then later delete the shared one but I want to use the move file API.

I'm requesting along with access token retrieved previously, the request looks like:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drives/{drive_id}/items/{item-id}
```

and I'm getting following response:

```
{
  "error": {
       "code": "invalidRequest",
       "message": "Bad Argument",
       "innerError": {
           "request-id": "45d8b6a2-345a-44b7-a61e-abababababb",
           "date": "2017-12-11T11:22:29"
       }
   }
}
```

Can someone please tell me which thing I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a supported operation. You can only move a file within a single Drive, not from one Drive to another. From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_move):

> Items cannot be moved between [Drives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/resources/drive) using this request.

Comment: So the best way to achieve this is to copy and then later delete the remote drive item, the client software might be doing the same.Thanks for help.

Comment: @Pratik, are you targeting consumer or business drives?

Comment: @Brad I'm targeting both drives.